# Ignoring escape sequence in C

Tags: arrays, c

I need to enter a matrix of size NxN of integers.
My idea is to enter it as a sequence of chars into char array and proceed working with it.
Matrix is given into stdin all at once.
The problem is to ignore escape characters (e.g. "\n") and enter all NxN integers as one string where integers will be separated with space.
Matrix itself is copied from txt file.
Input must end when Enter key is pressed.

```
//en axample of what I'm trying to reach
char buff[512];
gets(buff);
/*1 2 9 10 25
4 3 8 11 24
5 6 7 12 23
16 15 13 14 22
17 18 19 20 21*/

printf("%s", buff);
/*1 2 9 10 25
4 3 8 11 24
5 6 7 12 23
16 15 13 14 22
17 18 19 20 21/*
```

I tried using gets but it ended reading symbols when "\n" is reached.

Initial code looks like this:

```
int main(){
int size;
printf("enter size of matrix >> ");
scanf("%d",&size);

int matrix[size][size];
char allNumbers[size][512];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    fgets(allNumbers[i], 511, stdin);
}
printf("%s", allNumbers[2]);
return 0;
```

}

input:`1 2 9 10 25\n 4 3 8 11 24\n 5 6 7 12 23\n 16 15 13 14 22\n 17 18 19 20 21\0`

output:
1 2 9 10 25

Comment: "using gets but it ended reading symbols when "\n" is reached." --> That is what `gets()` does.  How else to you want to convey to code that input is done?  If you want to read 5 lines you need 5 calls.  Better with `fgets()` than obsolete `gets()`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica still no idea how to do it propperly. Matrix is given as one whole text with "\n"s and spaces. I don't quite understand how to embody iterative processing of input when it is only given one time.

Comment: Did you try 5 calls of `fgets()` as suggested earlier?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I tried calling fgets() in for() cycle.
It also gets more complicated as initial size of matrix is unknown and has to be input as well.

Comment: Time to post your code rather than only describe it.  Also post  input used and output seen. 
 Simply append your newer approach.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I struggle to manage propper editing, hope it looks reasonable for you.

Comment: What was the input used in response to `printf("enter size of matrix >> "); scanf("%d",&size);`?  Note do not  use `scanf()` with `fgets()` for now.  drop the `scanf()` call and replace with `fgets(some_buffer...); sscanf(some_buffer, "%d",&size);`.

Comment: Your input is a *stream* of characters and a program can consume a stream in whatever pieces it wants. If you use `fgets`, these pieces are *lines*.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica input for size was 5. Honestly, i don't understand at all how functions you suggested should work in my case :<.

Comment: @cucurbita Best to amend your post and put the true input which included the `"5\n"`.  Being honest is good, yet " i don't understand at all " exaggerates does not detail what is not understood.  Good luck.

Comment: @user3121023 Yes, I am pasting the text.  Input should end with symbol of input end. I am a newbie to C, not quite sure what that symbol is

Comment: @cucurbita – _My idea is to enter it as a sequence of chars into char array and proceed working with it._ Why do you develop a complicating idea instead of simply reading directly from `stdin`?

Comment: There are no escape sequences here. What you are representing with the digraph `\n` is a literal newline character.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using one char array for input.
Generally do not use both `scanf` and `fgets`.
This uses `fgets` to read a line with the size and `sscanf` to parse the integer from the line.
The same array is used to read the lines pasted from the file.
The loop continues until an empty line is read.
It may be necessary to hit enter a few times to exit the loop.
This does not parse the integers from the file. `sscanf` can be used to accomplish that as well. `strtol` is another parsing option.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( void) {
    char input[512] = "";
    int size = 0;
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    int used = 0;

    printf ( "enter size of matrix >> ");
    fflush ( stdout);
    if ( ! fgets ( input, sizeof input, stdin)) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "problem fgets\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if ( 1 != sscanf ( input, "%d", &size)) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "problem sscanf for size\n");
        return 2;
    }

    int matrix[size][size];
    for ( row = 0; row < size; ++row) {
        for ( col = 0; col < size; ++col) {
            matrix[row][col] = 0;
        }
    }

    row = 0;
    printf ( "enter matrix values >> ");
    while ( fgets ( input, sizeof input, stdin)){
        if ( '\n' == input[0]) {
            break;
        }
        printf ( "\nrow %d     %s", row, input);
        offset = 0;
        if ( row < size) {
            // parse integers from input;
        }
        ++row;
    }

    for ( row = 0; row < size; ++row) {
        for ( col = 0; col < size; ++col) {
            printf ( "%4d ", matrix[row][col]);
        }
        printf ( "\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```